# when I turn to fullscreen my pygame window, the screen fill option dosen't fill the whole screen

Tags: python

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

height=1000
width=600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((height, width), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("")
screen.fill(color='#0093ad')
pygame.display.flip()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```

when I try to run this code, it will only fill the area that was already filled when it was minimized and will not fill the screen when I maximize the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that fill simply changes the color values of the points specified in the fill (from 0,0 to current window x, current window y) it does not set the background color.

I wasn't able to find a way to have Pygame set the default window color

Neverless an easy and sometimes more usfull alternative is to just place the `fill` and `flip` functions in the loop, replacing the previous fills with a new correctly sized one.

that code would look a bit like

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

height=1000
width=600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((height, width), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("")
run = True
while run:
    screen.fill(color='#0093ad') #moved fill & flip inside the loop
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```